# Regular subrings of a polynomial ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I have the following situation: $\mathbb{C} \subseteq D \subseteq R$ is affine (= finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra), noetherian, has field of fractions $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and $R$ is separable over $D$ (= $R$ is a projective $R \otimes_D R$-module).

It would be great if one can show (at least) one of the following:
(1) Without any further assumptions, $D$ is regular (= a noetherian ring such that every localization at a maximal ideal is a regular local ring).
(2) Assuming integrality of $D \subseteq R$ (but not assuming flatness) implies regularity of $D$.
(3) Assuming flatness of $D \subseteq R$ (but not assuming integrality) implies regularity of $D$.

I am most interested to show (1); however, I am afraid there is not enough information to show (1), so showing (2) would be great too. (3) may be of some interest.

Thus far I can show only a special case of (3), namely: If $D \subseteq R$ is faithfully flat, then $D$ is regular.
Reason: Just apply Proposition 8 in Bourbaki's book, 10, page 59, which says the following: If $A$ and $B$ are noetherian rings with $A \to B$ faithfully flat, then regularity of $B$ implies regularity of $A$.

Sorry for not posting (yet) the specific case I have in mind; it's just that I first wish to know if the more general case is provable (maybe it can be found in a book or a paper?).

Comment: If I understand well you want a criterion to decide when such $D$ is regular. For $n=1$ flatness is good enough?

Comment: Yes, I want a criterion to decide the regularity of $D$. For $n=1$ your criterion sounds good-- Do you have a proof/reference for it? What happens when $n=2$?

Comment: For $n=1$, $D$ contains a monic polynomial, so $D\subset\mathbb C[X]$ is integral.

Comment: If the extension is integral, then flatness is enough.

Comment: Yes, because integral+flat imply faithfully flat, and then there is an exercise, for example in Matsumura's book, that claims that if $A \subseteq B$ is faithfully flat and $A$ and $B$ have the same field of fractions, then $A=B$.

Comment: For $n=1$, you claimed (hinted) that flatness implies integrality (I am not sure I know how to prove this). For $n=2$ is it true that flatness implies integrality? (I guess no). Actually, I have a special interest in the following case: $n=2$, the extension is separable, I do not mind to assume that it is integral, and I do not know that it is flat. Is separability (+integrality) of the extension implies regularity of $D$?

Comment: I don't understand much from your comments. When I said that your rings have the same field of fractions? When I said that integrality implies flatness? Integrality **and** flatness is enough, this is what I've meant.

Comment: Sorry, I had in mind a special case which interests me where $D$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ have the same field of fractions, $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$. For $n=1$ I did not understand why $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$ is integral, so I erroneously thought that flatness was involved (since you first suggested flatness).

Comment: It would be great if you can please answer the $n=1$ and $n=2$ cases; I am curious to see the exact claim and proof.

Comment: "For n=1, D contains a monic polynomial, so D⊂C[X] is integral." Which part isn't clear?

Comment: The field of fractions of $D$ is not necessarily $\mathbb C(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. For example, $D$ could be $\mathbb C[x_1]$ and $n$ larger than $1$. You seem to be mixing what you know in your (hidden) concrete situation and the statement of the question, which seems to be more general. It would probably be a good idea to clean up a bit the question, which is rather interesting!

Comment: @user26857: Thank you very much for your time and effort! I apologize for not being clear enough (I have edited my question).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks for your comment! I hope that after editing my question it is not less interesting than before.

Comment: Isn't better to post the example you think about instead of looking for a general criterion that we only guess what conditions should fulfill?

Comment: Posting my specific example has the advantage of having more chances that someone will be able either to prove that $D$ is regular or say he/she thinks there is not enough information in order to decide if $D$ is regular or not. However, I prefer not to bring my specific example at the moment, because I first wish to know if my general question has a known answer (only recently I have started to research regular rings/algebraic geometry, so I am probably ignorant of some known results; I know a little about ring theory). Sorry if this makes my question more difficult to answer.

Comment: Denote $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. The conditions that my specific example fulfills are: $\mathbb{C} \subseteq D \subseteq R$ is affine, noetherian, has field of fractions $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, and  $R$ is separable over $D$. Thant's it. Now, if one can show one of the following (in descending order of priority), that would be great: (1) Without any further assumptions, $D$ is regular. (2) Assuming integrality of $D \subseteq R$ (but not assuming flatness) implies regularity of $D$. (3) Assuming flatness of $D \subseteq R$ (but not assuming integrality) implies regularity of $D$.

Comment: As the question stands, it claims that if $D$ is regular then its field of fraction coincides with that of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, which is not true. Again, I suggest you clean up the question a bit. For example, sarting from your comment above which is the clearest statement of the problem so far!

Comment: Sorry for the probably trivial question, but can you please explain your first sentence? If I understand correctly, you meant the following: If one shows that $D$ is regular, then $D=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Maybe I should have mentioned that getting $D=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is fine with me. My problem is that I do not yet know how to show that $D$ is regular. (The case $n=2$ is good enough for me, if this simplifies things). I will edit my question according to your suggestions.

Comment: By first sentence refers to the version f your question before the last edit: it claimed that if $D$ is a f.g. algebra such that $\mathbb C\subseteq D\subseteq\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_]$ and which is regular, then the fraction field of $D$ coincides with that of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_]$. This is false, as an example I mentioned many comments ago shows. You probably did not mean to write that but you did. :-)

Comment: What I meant (and was misunderstood, maybe because English is not my first language): If $\mathbb{C} \subseteq D \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra having field of fractions $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, then I asked if one can show that such $D$ is regular. (My goal is to show that a specific $D$ is regular). Anyway, thank you very much for reading on my question and commenting on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the three things you want may be true.

First an example for 2, which will say 1 is false too. Take $D=\mathbb{C}[x^2-1,x(x^2-1), y]$.

For 3, take $D=\mathbb{C}[y^2x-1,(y^2x-2)^2x, y]$.

Comment: Thanks! How one shows that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is separable over $D$?

Comment: It is a calculation that is better done on paper. Most important thing to notice is that if $M$ is a maximal ideal of $D$, $M\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is a product of (two) maximal ideals in the first case and a maximal ideal in the second. What in algebraic geometry is called an unramified map.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints!